# How to extract auc scores from scikitplot plot_precision_recall method?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, auc

I am trying to get the micro-average score as displayed in:

```
from scikitplot.metrics import plot_precision_recall

plot_precision_recall(np.array(y_test), y_pred_proba)
plt.show()
```

For example, I have the plot:

[image]

with micro-average of 0.975

I've tried using the `auc` method with `precision_recall_curve` and `average_precision_score` among other methods, but the results are not the same. If I could just extract the desired `auc` score from the `plot_precision_recall` method itself, that would be easiest.

I believe the issue is that, as per the documentation, use of the `average='micro'` argument "Will be ignored when y_true is binary" and thus the macro average is being reported, at least for `roc_auc_score`. For `average_precision_score` it's reporting only the PR AUC for the positive class.

*NB*: I am not including a reproducible example because I only want to get the respective scores from the `plot_precision_recall` method.

I've Googled up a storm with negative results.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this:

```
clf = LogisticRegression().fit(X, y)

roc_auc_score(y, clf.predict_proba(X), average='micro')
```

I think it's going to be easier than trying to get the score from a plot.

Comment: It gives me the macro average AUC for the ROC curves, not for the PR curves.

Comment: please see edit above

Comment: Maybe look for the implementation of the plot function, which one are you using?

Comment: Yeah, that was my last resort. Using version 1.0.2.

Comment: Also I can't find the function plot_precision_recall. Is from sklearn or did you made it?

Comment: Oops! Good catch! I am correcting this in an edit. It's actually from scikitplot.metrics.

Comment: I found the magic here: https://github.com/reiinakano/scikit-plot/blob/master/scikitplot/metrics.py#L773